# Simple tool for minify/uglify and merge entire project to one single file?

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs2

Im looking for a while for a tool that will be able to run on a base folder and merge all javscript files to a single minified file.
I looked at uglifyjs2 which seems to be the favorite, but doesnt handle `require` calls:
I tried using the command line compress method on several files, but require calls will remain and will break the code on runtime if I try to run it separately

`uglifyjs routes/* libs/* config/* models/* server.js -o server.min.js -c sequences,dead_code,booleans,conditionals,properties,unused,if_return,join_vars,hoist_vars`

So I cant really make the "single" file version, only to uglify and generate a minified version for each file, but the entire project structure remains.
I also tried to experience with node-optimize, but it will leave many trails in the code, with `__FAKE_REQUIRE__` declarations holding the full path for my files, even though it was initially relative only (being a full path, its not portable to other computers)

Is there a reasonable way to generate a single file with the content of the entire project and then to uglify it, having a good and easy (single file) distribution release?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grunt for this purpose. For this, first of all you can specify in it that what your sources are. After that you can concat on them and then uglify/minify to get a single file. Please check this resource http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a mix of [browserify](http://browserify.org) and [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?hl=en)

With browserify you can keep your source code nicely separated while developing ("requiring" files in CommonJS format) and then generate a single "bundle" file when moving into production. Then you can minify that single file (and others if you wish, including 3rd party libraries) with Closure Compiler (or even with uglifyjs).